# Trying to get threads to work with a member function

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have this class

```
class ConnectionManager()
{
    public:
        void Receive(); /* This method uses variables from this class */
} 

void _tmain()
{
    ConnectionManager* m_pConnectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
    /* the thread should be called here */
}
```

How do I create a thread that uses the receive method from the m_pConnectionManager object? I can't seem to figure it out with the other questions on Stackoverflow.
I tried with this but it doesn't work:

```
std::thread receiveThread(&ConnectionManager::Receive);
```

I get this error:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional
```

Comment: You either need a `static` method or a class instance.

Comment: But if I have a static method the variables don't work. And I do have a class instance it's called m_pConnectionManager. If I make a thread with m_pConnectionManager->Receive() it throws another error

Comment: How about `std::thread receiveThread(&ConnectionManager::Receive, m_pConnectionManager);`?

Comment: That seems to have done it (it does not throw errors). Thanks a lot :)